# Create view with a filter based on a date column

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have a list with information regarding when we last visited our clients, two of the columns are:

**Last** - This is a date picker which tells us the last time we visited the client

**Next** - This is also a date picker which tells us when we will be visiting the client next

[image: List]

I want to create a view called 'Flagged' with a filter that shows us which client visits we missed based on the next column

So for example if we have to visit a client called 'CompanyA' on the 20th of October and we miss that date, 'CompanyA' will show in the flagged view.

I'm just not sure how to build the filter

[image: Filter Image]

Thanks

Comment: how you tell/enter the value in sharepoint, i mean if you miss a date then how sharepoint know about it?

Comment: If we have to visit the client on the 20th of October and then on the 21st Of October we have not changed the next column date the item is shown in the view

Answer (score 0):

What i Understand is that if you set the Next date to Oct 20th and you miss it then you will not change it. Now you want to create a view which will show you if you miss a date.

I think you filter is simple, if Next is less then Today. like this.

[image]